# do we have the statement works as if {0} in TCL?

Tags: tcl

In TCL, I wonder if we have some statements just like `if {0} {...}`, I mean I do not want to use `if {0} {...}`, so do we have other alternative?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you trying to say "if something is false, then don't do something"?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create any command you want to work the same way. In the following example I create a command named "-" that accepts arbitrary arguments and does nothing. The only caveat is that you must use balanced quoting:

```
proc - args return

- {
    this code/data will not execute
}
- neither will this
- "this won't execute either"
```

Of course, with those last two examples, variable and command substitution may happen, depending on what follows the '-'

Comment: If you used an empty body, Tcl would recognize that it is able to compile it out completely.